# Building graph structure from GIS data in Python

Tags: python, graph, gis, shortest-path

I want to implement a driving direction in Python using something like Djikstra's shortest path. The algorithm requires the data to be represents in graph structure. Raw GIS data (e.g. shape files or [OpenStreetMap data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features), however, represent their data differently. Therefore, I was wondering is there any Python library that can convert GIS data to graph structure?

In Java I found that GeoTools has [exactly what I described](http://communitymapbuilder.org/display/GEOTDOC/Graphs). Is there any similar library in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used it yet, but there's a function that generates directed graphs from shapefiles in Networkx: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/readwrite.nx_shp.html. If it doesn't do exactly what you need, it might suggest a solution. Uses OGR's Python bindings to read data.

See also Graphserver http://bmander.github.com/graphserver/.

Comment: That's exactly I was looking for. Also thank you for mentioning GraphServer.